# Designintf.dcu not found in custom component

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I am here converting some customize delphi component to latest delphi xe5.
I already build it in delphi xe5 ide and where desgninf i replaced with
designintf and design editor.
i also include designide.dcp in reference .
it build and install sucessfully .
but there some packages while i try to use and complie error like
designinf.dcu not found come .

i study on internet for solution 
as after delphi 6  their delphi not redistributed their design time 
packges. but because it in delphi 5 and complex one i can invest 
time on dividing design and runtime code and test it.

kindly any alternative solution.

thanks
abhishek mestri

Comment: I think we need more detail. Also, please don't tag the question with irrelevant tags. I cannot see xe2 or xe in the question. Should be delphi-xe5

Comment: i used xe or xe2 tag as this is common problem for those who using old component and want to migrate any version from delphi xe to latest one they are facing. please any solution or direction suggest

Comment: I was going to suggest `designide.dcp` but you already mentioned it. One thought is if you are mixing designtime and runtime units you could run into trouble and may get errors like this.

Comment: You are using xe5 and should tag it so. Yes, mixing runtime and designtime is a likely cause. But we don't have enough detail to say much more.

Comment: yes but problem is there approx 54 component and thousands of lines. i cant changes it . as after change it require test . all because of this most delphi company worry about migration.

Comment: If you want help, you'll make a simple example to show us what your scenario is.

Comment: i think will do but its common problem, sure every delphi developer facing. i just want why it not get supported from delphi ide instend of make changes on our component and divide it into design and runtime . any alternative solution for it.

Comment: Nobody can give you a solution until they know what the problem is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such errors often happen if you take very old (Delphi 6 or before) component code and try to compile it in a newer compiler.

The unit `designintf.dcu` and some other units are only available to packages that link with the IDE, i.e. only for design time code. In older versions of Delphi, you would get the source code, but not anymore, because the packages in which these units are are not redistributable, they are exclusively meant for the IDE.

So at the time of Delphi 6 and 7, youw were warned to separate code that would be used at runtime and code that could only be used at designtime, by the IDE. The old component you are using did not do that, yet.

So try to find out which code actually requires `designintf.dcu`, move that code to a separate unit, and make it use the original unit. The original unit is now the runtime code, can be used everywhere, and doesn't need `designintf.dcu`. The other unit is the designtime unit and should only be linked into the package used to install the component in the IDE.

More info: [Delphi FAQ](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/delphi/vcl/f266.shtml)

Comment: hi sir thanks, yes component which i am modifying is even with delphi 5, and i want to convert it to delphi xe5. but here whole component set and linked or inherited from each other and also some are creating at runtime. so changing component code it make restructure or testing whole senario. is there any way to avoid it? if not refer some book which will help me this component design and code . this component design and code new dimensions to me.

Comment: Hi Sir sorry But Today I was testing same component code on Delphi 5 and as per resource on internet Borland stop distribution of designintf.dcu  after Delphi 5 . Then why in Delphi 5 also showing me same error that DsgnIntF.Dcu not found?

Comment: I guess that you did not put the needed package in the `requires` section of your designtime package.

Comment: I had already gave require packages because it compiled successfully . my issue with while using that component error come.

Comment: I can't tell from here why the component doesn't work, sorry.

Comment: The answer above is 100% correct, after some struggling myself with the above issue, most Delphi pros would probably say, "Of Course!" but for those who need some more clarity:

 - Components can be runtime and design time
 - Some components have design time editors
 - Design time editors cannot live during runtime (Depends on DesignEdit & DesignIntf)

Separating these out into different units as suggested above worked like a charm.  Go look for code running RegisterComponentEditor and make sure it is not trying to be included when your actual program is building or running.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone that's having difficulty linking **DesignIntf** and/or **DesignEditors**, try adding designide.dcp to the package's *Requires* folder. For example, the dcp for XE3 can be found in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\lib\win32\release
```

Comment: I had to add the path ``C:\Programme\Borland\Delphi7\Source\ToolsAPI`` to the search path, too

Answer (score 0):

> I already build it in delphi xe5 ide and where desgninf i replaced
> with designintf and design editor.
>
> but there some packages while i try to use and complie error like
> designinf.dcu not found come

Based on your limited description, it seems to me that some of your packages might still expect to find designinf.pas file which you renamed to designintf.pas.

So I would go recheck all of the packages which don't compile so that they try to include the correct file and not the one which no longer exists.