# How to solve error 'DesignIntf.dcu' not found in Project (Not Package)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

I've done a lot of research before asking here so I already tried to *add -LUDesignIDE* to the compiler options.

However it was enough to *add 'DesignIDE' to the requires part* of the package files 
but in my .exe files - so pure project files with some units - I don't know what to do to solve this DesignIntf.dcu not found problem?

They don't even use DesignIntf directly and when I add it to the uses part, still - not found.

The subject is an update from Delphi2007 to Delphi2010.

I would be pleased if there is anybody who may have some other possible solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use designtime code at runtime, which is what the error indicates you're trying to do. Remove the designtime code, which removes the need for DesignIntf. If the IDE is insisting you need it, it's there somewhere. You'll need to look harder. [This previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24806085/62576) may help.

Comment: The unit you are describing is *only* supposed to be used in a design-time package, nowhere else. There is absolutely no reason for it to be used anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this solved the extraordinary problem:

In .dpk files you can add 'DesignIDE' in the requires section.

In .dpr files you can do things like that in the uses section->

```
DesignIntf in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\source\ToolsAPI\de\DesignIntf.pas',
DesignerTypes in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\source\ToolsAPI\DesignerTypes.pas',
  DesignMenus in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\source\ToolsAPI\DesignMenus.pas';
```

[The path above is for Delphi 2010, yours can be different]

So it's about which Units you exactly need and to put them into your project.

And yes, the commentators are right but as I wrote in the headline, it's not about a package, the packages are all divided in dcl and non dcl, it is about projects using non dcl packages but requiring Design units.